How do I handle up to 40 Amps continuous current in an ESC (Electric Speed Controller) for my PCB? Specifically heat generation
I have an electric longboard that can consume up to 40 Amps continuously. Here is my schematic:

I have a couple questions.

Do both the high side and low side MOSFETs experience the same heat generation as current goes through the high side MOSFET, through the BLDC motor, and back through the low side MOSFET?

How do I know how thick to make my pcb traces between MOSFETs to handle 40 Amps continous current? Or should I instead connect a 12 gauge wire to the leads of my MOSFET pins and disregard doing a PCB trace?

I was looking at the open source esc called VESC. They have a metal plating under the MOSFETs. Do I need to do something like this as well so the MOSFETs don't burn my PCB?


I am a beginner and don't have much experience dealing with heat generation and high currents so I am in great need of some guidance. Main goal is I don't want my PCB to heat up too much to where it burns up and no longer works.

Please link data sheets for the MOSFETs and explain why you must diode external reverse diodes across them.

@Andyaka external diodes have nothing to do with the MOSFET itself. The diodes provide regenerative braking from the BLDC motor which is why they are included.

How do you dissipate the expected 6-7 W heat per MOSFET under full load? What kind of cooling do you want to use?

@Jens i'm not exactly sure. The open source VESC I have linked above just uses a medal pad directly under the MOSFET so I am thinking something similar to this? I am not very experienced with dissipating heat.
